# Opinion: Reason to use NoSQL

Tags: database, nosql

I got two opinions about NoSQL from my friend.

**First:** Use NoSQL to boost performance and save occasional updated data. Still use sql to save all important dan transaction data.

**Second:** Don't use NoSQL if you didn't really need it. Use it if you really save big data.

I've used NoSQL and its really fast when selecting data.

I want to know, is first opinion only enough for implementing NoSQL? What all of you think about these?

**NOTE:** In my case, it still running well with SQL. I want to add NoSQL for improving data reading speed. so it will work alongside.

*Is it worth it to use NoSQL this early?*

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I mean is it worth it to use NoSQL when we haven't deal with big data yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you are designing.

From my experience scaling out data collection I have found traditional relational storage to be a bottleneck in terms of its inability to scale out over multiple nodes when a databases gets very large. Sure it scales up but this becomes cost prohibitive at some point.  In this scenario it would therefore depend on your medium to long term data storage projections. The solution for me was therefore mixture of relational storage for data that may be updated frequently and noSQL (document storage) for data the has a fast rate of growth that is generally not updated post write.

Things to take into account:

## Queries

> SQL relational storage supports a growing subset languages for queries, as well as a wide range of filters, sorting options, and projections and index queries. NoSQL does all this as well, but SQL can often go beyond it, allowing powerful aggregations of your data as well, beyond what NoSQL can do.

## Transactions

> Transactions are important because they ensure that you have atomically made changes to your database. Many NoSQL platforms don’t support transactions, so be aware of this feature when you’re figuring out which to use, and what your own needs are.

## Consistency

> MySQL platforms often use a single master to guarantee strong consistency in your database. These use synchronous replication to ensure you don’t lose important changes queued up to the master. NoSQL, by contrast, does replication of entity groups without a master, so that data is strong within an entity group, and is eventually updated across all groups. The better option depends on the constraints and needs of your database.

## Scalability

> For years, database administrators relied on scaling up, buying bigger servers as database load increased. However, as transaction rates and demands on the databases continue to expand immensely, emphasis is on scaling out instead. Scaling out is distributing databases across multiple hosts, and that’s something NoSQL does better than standard SQL. They’re designed for optimal use on scaled out databases.

## Management

> NoSQL databases are generally designed to require less management overall. Repairs are often automatic, and data distribution and simpler data models contribute to less administration required overall. However, you’ve also got less support when there’s a problem. SQL platforms often have vendors waiting to supply support to enterprises.

## Schema

> Regular SQL platforms often have strictly enforced rules for a schema change, to stave off user-created typos that can put faults in your query. NoSQL platforms will have their own mechanisms for combating this.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i still wonder. What if my current SQL is enough for now, but i want to add NoSQL for optimizing data reading speed. In this case i use SQL and NoSQL alongside. Is this worth it? or should I just optimizing my query, sharding, etc?

Answer (score 1):

NoSQL scores over SQL in below areas

> - It support semi-structured data and volatile data. You can change the structure at any time
> - It does not have schema
> - Read/Write through put is very high
> - Horizontal scalability is easily achieved - Add cheaper hardware and provide right replication factor
> - Will support Bigdata in volumes of Terra Bytes & Peta Bytes by using cheaper hardware
> - Good support for Analytic tools on top of Bigdata, especially Hadoop/Hbase family
> - In memory caching option is available to increase the performance of queries
> - Faster development life cycles for developers

When you should not use NoSQL and go for SQL

> - If you require business critical transaction with ACID properties i.e where Consistency is key & Eventual consistency is not an option
> - If you have heavy aggregation queries spanning multiple entities

In summary, you have to use right technology for right business use case. i.e combination of SQL and NoSQL

Regarding your queries:

1. Use SQL for business critical transactions. If your SQL is scaling for your business requirements, use SQL.
2. Use NoSQL for huge volumes of data in magnitudes of Tera/Peta bytes with variety of data , where SQL can't handle that volume & variety.

Answer (score 0):

As others pointed out both SQL and NoSQL (Not only SQL) have their advantages.

There is often temptation to use both side by side and get maximum out of it. Something referred to as [Polyglot persistence](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/PolyglotPersistence.html)

Is it a good idea? Sometimes, yes.

Should I do it? 
While it may have benefits, the trade off comes with maintenance of multiple stores (note: they would have different ways of database management).
Also the data sync is a bigger one if you are planning this for same transactional system.
If the data you are going to store (in sql and no-sql databases) can be logically separated then you might be ok. But in case they are closely related then you are going to have tough time keeping them consistent.

Overall when i evaluated this option, i came to conclude that it would work only when you can logically partition the data. Another use case may be using Nosql for Analytics and continue with sql for transaction system.

Going back to your use case, did you try JSON storage within your sql database. It may give you benefit of performance without much tradeoffs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In this situation I haven't try JSON storage yet. Currently It's using MSSQL with normalize structure. The server using 8GB RAM, I think I can add more RAM since its using MSSQL Enterprise. I'm wondering should I add more RAM or start using NoSQL to optimize system performance?

Comment: I can't really comment if additional RAM will improve the situation. You would need to closely analyse your workload to locate and fix bottlenecks.

Comment: Now I get it. the important thing is I should aware of the trade off of using NoSQL and should analyse the bottlenecks then make decision from it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: agreed. Its not necessary that switching to NoSql would magically weed out performance issues. Think about Facebook using mysql and still getting a good bit out of it. Its important to figure out the bottlenecks first and then take corrective action. It could lead you to nosql or better indexing